# Braintree checkout gives error `Braintree::ConfigurationError` after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, e-commerce, braintree

Hi I deployed an App to a VPS yesterday using Passenger/Capistrano and Nginx server.

All is running smoothly except when I enter the `checkout`button on the order page.

Then the app crashes and in the `production.log`there is this error line  `Braintree::ConfigurationError (Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id needs to be set):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:22:in 'new'`

The thing is that the `Merchiant_id`is set and I'm totally lost.

before the deploy I changed the `Sandbox` API keys to `Production`API keys in `application.yml`. I'm using `figaro` to hide the `API keys`.

When I ran this on the `localhost`before deploy everything worked fine.

I've went through the Braintree guides again and again. I can't find anything wrong.

Am I missing something here?

here is the `orders_controller.rb` were the error is coming from.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

include CurrentCart
before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]

def index
    @orders = Order.all? 
end

def new
    @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
 @random_no = rand(5)
 @random_image = @images[@random_no]

    if @cart.product_items.empty?
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
        return

    end
    @order = Order.new
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate #this is line 22 were the error is
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        charge
        if @result.success?
            @order.add_product_items_from_cart(@cart)
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver 
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order'
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Please Check Your Cart'
            redirect_to root_url, alert: @result.message
            @order.destroy
        end
    else
        @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
        render :new
    end
end


def show

end


def destroy
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order deleted'
end

private

def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :country)
end

def charge
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        amount: @cart.total_price_usd,
        payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce] )
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, basically it was the same Error.

What I did to solve this in my case was to add `config/application.yml` to `set :linked_files` in the `deploy.rb``

so the line would look something like this `set :linked_files, %w{ config/application.yml}`

then before you deploy again you must create the `application.yml` on the server. Most likely it is in `~/YOURAPP/shared/config$`

And you copy/paste the code from the `application.yml` on your machine to the `~/YOURAPP/shared/config/application.yml`

I can almost bet that adding this will fix your problem

Comment: No....i get a new error, missing application.yml on the server..... Guess I have to created it on the server

Comment: Omg thank you so much this fixed my error, everything is working now :)